# How do I get my nylon hop bags clean and porous again?

Tags: hops, boil

Although I thoroughly clean my nylon hop bags after each boil they have become non-porous. I’ve tried boiling with no improvement to porosity. Any suggestions for getting them porous again?

Comment: How are you cleaning them?

Answer (score 2):

Throw your tight mesh bags away and find some with a mesh that is more open.  I use a coarser mesh bag intended for adding fruit for winemaking.  Lets a little more particulate through but always Works great.